# Recovery Mode Fails on Samsung Galaxy i7500L

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-i7500

I'm trying [these steps](http://anonymous00.hubpages.com/hub/Samsung-Galaxy-i7500-Android-Rooting-Bell-Canada) to root my Samsung Galaxy i7500L.

When I get to step 9, recovery mode, I just see a yellow exclaimation-mark icon over a phone icon. I can reset my phone to OEM settings, but I can't see any menu or enable SU/Root.

I tried copying the rectools.tar.gz to my root folder (I assume this is the folder that opens as a drive when you plug in to your PC via USB and select "open files/folder" -- I think you need Mass Storage mode enabled though). Is that the right place?

Also, even if I reset and then just run straight recovery (without running fastboot to flash first), I see the same screen.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you're not successfully replacing the stock recovery (the "yellow exclaimation-mark icon over a phone icon") with the new one they instruct you to download. Step 7 is key:

> 7) Type `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`

This is where they have you 'flash' (copy/format) the modified recovery over the stock recovery. Is this step working for you? Simply copying the 'RECTOOLS.tar.gz' to your device's storage or SD card isn't sufficient.

On a separate note, have you investigated other means of rooting your device besides manually flashing via ADB? My favorite guide is [Lifehacker's](http://lifehacker.com/5789397/the-always-up+to+date-guide-to-rooting-any-android-phone), and if I read it right you might simply be able to use SuperOneClick.

In any event, as always, tread lightly and read carefully.

Comment: Tried SuperOneClick, didn't work. It's not about flashing the new recovery; I cannot boot the stock recover mode, under any circumstance. This is my issue.

Comment: @ashes999: Per your question, the screen with the yellow exclaimation-mark icon over a phone icon where you can reset your phone to OEM settings _is_ the stock recovery. Stock recovery won't let you Enable SU/Root, that's a function of a 3rd party recovery that must be flashed in place of your stock recovery.

Comment: Really? That's interesting. But then, there's no way out of it without wiping your phone completely. I definitely didn't get step 7 to work, but now I can't afford risking another wipe-out.

Comment: @ashes999: Well it's worth noting that flashing a new recovery shouldn't wipe your existing ROM or data, it would only change the recovery partition (a good explanation of the difference is [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/)). Every time you're talking about recovery or rooting, though, you should make backups and be prepared for possible data loss.